# Solving Hanoi towers in CLIPS

Tags: clips, towers-of-hanoi

Good evening, i have problem with solving Hanoi towers in CLIPS i tried to help myself with AI but its not helping this is the code i wrote :

```
(deffunction make-game ()
  (make-instance 'game (make-list 3)))

(defrule init-game
  (not (game))
  =>
  (make-game))

(defrule move-ring
  (game (towers (member $t1 $towers))
    (tower $t1 (rings $r1 $r2 $r3))
    (tower (member $t2 $towers) (rings))
    (tower (member $t3 $towers) (rings))
    (test (not (eq $r1 $r2))
      (not (eq $r1 $r3))
      (not (eq $r2 $r3)))
  =>
  (modify-tower $t1 (remove $r1))
  (modify-tower $t2 (append $r1))
  (print-game))


(defrule print-game
  (game (towers (list $t1 $t2 $t3)))
  =>
  (print "Tower 1: " (tower-rings $t1))
  (print "Tower 2: " (tower-rings $t2))
  (print "Tower 3: " (tower-rings $t3)))
```

its not working i have errors everywhere i dont understand CLIPS well, i need to use facts, rules etc to make this logical game to work... Thank you very much for your help!

I tried AI, nothing works i need fully functioned game of Hanoi Towers thanks!